# Table data not displaying in android

Tags: android, tablelayout

Hi In My Application Fetching the data from database displaying in table layout in android.

Now I have One submit button if I click submit button I want to display the data from database displaying into my layout.And I want Match with class and section based on I want to display the data.

Can Anyone please help me.

**class file**

```
public class Attend extends Activity {

    String data = "";
    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow tr;
    TextView label;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

        final DataseData getdb = new DataseData();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                data = getdb.getDataFromDB();
                System.out.println(data);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<Users> users = parseJSON(data);
                        addData(users);                     
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public ArrayList<Users> parseJSON(String result) {
        ArrayList<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Users user = new Users();
                user.setId(json_data.getInt("id"));
                user.setClassname(json_data.getString("classname"));
                user.setSectionname(json_data.getString("sectionname"));
                //user.setDate(json_data.getString("date"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
        }
        return users;
    }

    void addHeader(){

        tr = new TableRow(this);


        label = new TextView(this);
        label.setText("classname");
        label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(label,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); 


        TextView sectionname = new TextView(this);
        sectionname.setText("sectionname");
        sectionname.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        sectionname.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        sectionname.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(sectionname,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); 


        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        /*TextView date = new TextView(this);
        date.setText("date");
        date.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        date.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(date,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); 


        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));*/

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<Users> users) {

        addHeader();

        for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            Users p = (Users) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);

            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getClassname());
            label.setText(p.getSectionname());
            //label.setText(p.getDate());
            label.setId(p.getId());
            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);

            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll);


            TextView classname = new TextView(this);
            classname.setText(p.getClassname());
            classname.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            classname.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll.addView(classname,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); 


            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


            TextView sectionname = new TextView(this);
            sectionname.setText(p.getClassname());
            sectionname.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            sectionname.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll.addView(sectionname,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); 


            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


           TextView date = new TextView(this);
            date.setText(p.getClassname());
            date.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll.addView(classname,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); 


            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }
```

MainActivity.lass

```
public class AndroidSpinnerExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText fromDateEtxt;
    private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Spinner element
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Button submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Attend.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

        findViewsById();

        setDateTimeField();
        // Spinner click listener
        //spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> classnames = new ArrayList<String>();
        classnames.add("Select");
        classnames.add("Play Group");
        classnames.add("Nursery");
        classnames.add("Lkg");
        classnames.add("Ukg");
        classnames.add("Fifth");
        classnames.add("Sixth");
        List<String> sectionnames = new ArrayList<String>();
        sectionnames.add("Select");
        sectionnames.add("Batch A");
        sectionnames.add("Batch B");
        sectionnames.add("Batch C");
        sectionnames.add("Batch D");
        sectionnames.add("Batch E");
        sectionnames.add("Batch F");

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, classnames);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sectionnames);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
    }
    private void findViewsById() {
        fromDateEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_fromdate); 
        fromDateEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        fromDateEtxt.requestFocus();

        //toDateEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_todate);
        //toDateEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    }

    private void setDateTimeField() {
        fromDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);
        //toDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }

        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    }


    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == fromDateEtxt) {
            fromDatePickerDialog.show();
        } 

    }
```

Comment: you never get any answers untill not specify your requriements

Comment: Hi if match with classname and sectionname i want to display the data in table format in android

Comment: what is class name nad section name?